# Create sql querie for item list from items database

Tags: sql

I have a database with a list of item with active status and inactive status.
My table looks like :

```
ID item_name item_added_date item_removed_date item_status
```

What i am looking to learn is to get a output :

```
Year month opening_count closing_count inactived_items
```

Not sure how to go about this, i have a very basic sql knowledge. Is this possible to get?

Comment: Please add the tag for the database you are using (Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL, etc.) and add some sample data and sample of desired result so it's easier to understand what you need.

Comment: Please share some sample data for this table and your desired results from this sample data. It will help us understand exactly what you are after.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. [Formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)